# Laravel 5: Post - Pass Arguments To Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I think what I want is quite basic, I just can't find the proper syntax as I am still learning Laravel.

So, I am using google verification for sign ins on my website. This entails a post request to my backend that has to be handled, I have put this logic in a controller. My routes.php:

```
Route::post('google' ,  [
    'as' => 'verify.index',
    'uses' => 'verify@verifyIdToken'
]);
```

My controller (verify.php):

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class verify extends Controller
{
    public function verifyIdToken($token)
    {
        $token = $_POST['id'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        return $this->getAuth()->verifyIdToken($token);
        echo $this->getAuth()->verifyIdToken($token);
        return view('aviewII')->with(['verify' => json_encode(verifyIdToken($token)),'email'=> json_encode($email)]);
    }
}
```

Of course, because of how the function in the controller is written, I get the following error `Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\verify::verifyIdToken()` My question is, how do I tell the function in the controller to take `$_POST['id']` as the argument for `$token`?

Something like this:

```
Route::post('google' ,  [
        'as' => 'verify.index',
        'uses' => 'verify@verifyIdToken ~with $_POST['id'] as $token'
    ]);
```

For additional reference, my actual post request looks like this:

`$.post( "http://example.com/google", {email:profile.getEmail(),id:id_token} );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Laravel's `request` class. You should type-hint the class on your method, which then allows loads of options to actually obtain the data. Something like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function verifyIdToken(Request $request)
{
    $token = $request->input('id');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    return $this->getAuth()->verifyIdToken($token);
    echo $this->getAuth()->verifyIdToken($token);
    return view('aviewII')->with(['verify' => json_encode(verifyIdToken($token)),'email'=> json_encode($email)]);
}
```

The [documentation on it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests) has tons more useful information.

Answer (score 2):

Controller method:

```
public function verifyIdToken(Request $request)
{
    // Not necessary but a better practice for ajax 'POST' responses.

    if($request->ajax() &&  $request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        return $request::get('token');
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('google', ['as' => 'some.alias', 'uses' => 'SomeController@verifyIdToken']);
```